# how to create google maps custom marker which has an animating gif

Tags: google-maps, animation, google-maps-markers

I want to create a google map marker which has an animating gif.I know google maps has 2 animation drop and bounce.I want to create one except those.Is is possible to do this. Could you lead a way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MarkerOptions), in `google.maps.MarkerOptions` you can pass `optimized: false` if you want to use `gif` as marker icon:

> optimized Type: boolean
>
> Optimization renders many markers as a single
>   static element. Optimized rendering is enabled by default. Disable
>   optimized rendering for animated GIFs or PNGs, or when each marker
>   must be rendered as a separate DOM element (advanced usage only).

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
{
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    optimized: false,
    icon: "http://preloaders.net/preloaders/489/Classic%20map%20marker-32.gif"
});
```

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T78Hd/138/

Comment: Thanks a lot your effort.That's exactly what I want to.